# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

I am new to Python and am learning some basics. I would like to know why I am getting this error. The code is:

```
Hours = raw_input ("How many Hours you worked for today : ")
minutes = (Hours * 60)
Percentage = (minutes * 100) / 60
print "Today you worked : ", "percentage"
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to convert your `Hours` variable to a number, since `raw_input()` gives you a string:

```
Hours = int(raw_input("How many hours you worked for today: "))
```

The reason why this is failing so late is because `*` is defined for string and `int`: it "multiplies" the string by the int argument. So if you type `7` at the prompt, you'll get:

```
Hours = '7'
minutes = '777777....77777'        # 7 repeated 60 times
Percentage = '77777....77777' / 60 # 7 repeated 60*100 = 6000 times
```

So when it tries to do `/` on a string and a number it finally fails.

Answer (score 2):

`Hours` is read as a string. First convert it to an integer:

```
Hours = int(raw_input("..."))
```

Note that `Hours*60` works because that concatenates Hours with itself 60 times. But that certainly is not what you want so you have to convert to `int` at the first opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

Your value `Hours` is a string. To convert to an integer,

```
Hours = int(raw_input("How many hours you worked for today : "))
```

Values in Python have a specific *type*, and although a string may contain only digits, you still can't treat it as a number without telling Python to convert it. This is unlike some other languages such as Javascript, Perl, and PHP, where the language automatically converts the type when needed.

Comment: Type coercion *does* happen in Python though...

Comment: Yes, but only in legacy versions, and not in the case stated in the question. ["In Python 3.0, coercion will not be supported."](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#coercion-rules).

Comment: Well, [this](http://ideone.com/nxOz5) still works.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input()` returns a string. Convert it to a number before proceeding (since *multiplying* a string by an integer is a valid operation).